# .NET 6 : get database records by date except today's date EF Core?

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

I have a table in which the values ​​are recorded along with the date.

My date field is of string type:

```
"1401/09/23"
```

I want to get rows that date back to yesterday:

```
public async Task<List<Reservation>> GetReservations()
{
    return await _context.Reservations.OrderByDescending(r => r.DateReserve).ToListAsync();
}
```

I also used the following code, but it gives an error!

```
return await _context.Reservations.Where(r => DateTime.Parse(r.DateReserve, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= DateTime.Parse(DateConvertor.ToShamsi(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToListAsync();
```

Error :
[image]

Comment: First step: fix your database. Storing dates as strings is... really bad. For so many reasons.

Comment: @nvoigt I need to use Shamsi date so I have to store as string

Comment: I have no idea what that is and why you feel you "have to" use it. If you want dates, use date fields.

Comment: @nvoigt Because I can't store  the date in the correct shamsi format  `1401/01/01`

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy You can change the format of the date when you use it where you need the shamsi format. The `DateTime` class has a custom [`ToString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-tostring(system-string)) method, where you can use the shamsi format.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your code is correct functionally (I have no idea what a "Shamsi" is), you can fix your error by using ".AsEnumerable()":

```
return _context.Reservations.AsEnumerable().Where(r => DateTime.Parse(r.DateReserve, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) >= DateTime.Parse(DateConvertor.ToShamsi(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)).ToList();
```

Please note that this means that your complete table will be pulled into memory of your PC and the statement will be executed by C# code on your PC, instead of a database statement on your database.

Comment: `ToListAsync()` gives an error

Comment: Yes. The easiest option would be to use ToList(), but you can also read up on AsAsyncEnumerable() and use that instead.